# Functions submitted lazily

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I came across this function definition when studying the book "Functional Programming in Scala" by Paul Chiusano and Runar Bjanarson (Ch. 7 - Purely functional parallelism):

```
 def fork[A](a: => Par[A]): Par[A] = 
    es => es.submit(new Callable[A] {
      def call = a(es).get
    })
```

`Par[A]` is `type Par[A] = ExecutorService => Future[A]` and `ExecutorService` and `Future` are from the `java.util.concurrent` library. [Here](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/parallelism/Par.scala) is the full code on Github. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) for the `java.util.concurrent` documentation.

My questions it what it means to supply a function as a lazy argument? In particular, I can understand what it means to supply a computation lazily, but I am having trouble seeing what it implies in the case of a functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> supply a function as a lazy argument

For the `fork` function has a lazy argument `a: => Par[A]`, that's means `a` will not eval when `fork(a)` until it's submitted to `ExecutorService` with a `Callable`, since `a`'s response type also `Par[A]`, it will also asynchronously eval again, and also can **recursively** fork execute with the same **ExecutorService**.

So for my understanding, the `fork` with **lazy argument** `a: => Par[A]`, it will have the ability of parallel and recursively fork tasks.

---

In **Scala**, **lazy function**: it means **lazy evaluation** until invoke this function. for your example, you are declaring a **lazy function** `a: => Par[A]`, so when you call `fork` method like: `fork(myFunction())`, this will not evaluate `myFunction` immediately, it only will eval when `a(es).get` executed.

Example:

```
def fun(a: => Int): Int = {
  println("second run")
  a
}

def fun2(): Int = {
  println("first run")
  1 + 1
}

fun(fun2())
```

the above code will output like:

> second run
>
> first run

since submit `fun2()` as a `lazy function` will not evaluate by `fun(fun2())`, and it will be evaluated in method `fun`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all. The question was specifically about `=> (ExecutorService => Future[A])` as input type.

Comment: yes, it would be very helpful to see it in this context. But, @chengpohi's answer helped me as well. In particular, if fun did not take its argument lazily, then we would see "first run" before "second run", correct?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin@clog14 sorry misunderstanding the problem :(, I have updated my answer, hope it's helpful.

Comment: @chengpohi many thanks for making this a bit more precise. But, I still feel a bit uncertain. Can you maybe explain what would happen if the function did not accept its arguments lazily?

Comment: @clog14, if not accept its arguments lazily, it will **eval** immediately, example: `fork(a) + fork(b)`, the both `fork` function can't run parallel, it will run sequential,  if we let the argument is lazy, the both `fork` can run in parallel way.

Comment: I still have some difficulties seeing this. I think there are two levels here, first `fork(a) + fork(b)` is a function mapping an executor service into a `Future` . Then we can apply this function by actually passing the executor service. At what point of these two steps (if this is the correct way to think about it) does the laziness matter?

Comment: So it seems there is a difference between evaluation and execution which I do not understand.